# How can I set the line limit length for different types of files?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have the following gray line that limits the number of characters a single line can accomodate:[image]

I'd like to change the line length (this fill probably affect where this line is currently shown right now) for different files: for js, php files etc one line length, for HTML template files another. Is it possible? If not, how can I change at least for all file types?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is now possible as the bug linked by @LazyOne has been resolved. You can now set different right margins for different programming languages.

The setting is under ***Settings | Editor | Code Style | <Your language>*** on the ***Wrapping and Braces*** tab at the very top of the list.

[image: PhpStorm settings interface]

Answer (score 30):

Default value can be set at

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style --> Right margin (columns)**

[image]

Since end of 2014 (after [IDEA-59662 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59662) was implemented) most languages have an option to adjust that value in language-dedicated section. For example: PHP

[image]

---

For unsupported languages .. or those that do not have such option -- you may try going with `.editorconfig` file and EditorConfig Support plugin -- should work.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are from 2018:

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Hard Wrap At**
[image]

**Or Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Your Technology(ex. PHP) | Hard wrap at**

[image]