# How to make PhpStorm's run command to not wrap but inline to display?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I tried to find the answer, but the result is terrible. I have no idea how to deal with it. So I hope have some big guys to help me.

[image]

This is my IDE Info.

```
PhpStorm 2021.1.3
Build #PS-211.7442.50, built on June 2, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.57 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1524M
Cores: 4
Registry: run.processes.with.pty=TRUE, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.dubreuia (2.2.0), com.intellij.ideolog (203.0.27.0), com.mallowigi (36.0), com.pinkfloyded.idea-file-path-autocomplete.idea-file-path-autocomplete (0.4.1), com.thvardhan.gradianto (4.4), dev.meanmail.plugin.nginx-intellij-plugin (2021.2-211), net.vektah.codeglance (1.5.4), org.jetbrains.plugins.go-template (211.6693.44), zielu.gittoolbox (203.5.10), mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore (4.1.0), com.dmarcotte.handlebars (211.6693.44), cn.yiiguxing.plugin.translate (3.1.1), com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI (6.7.2), dev.ekvedaras.laravelquery (2.0.4), de.espend.idea.laravel (0.15.4), ru.adelf.idea.dingo (0.1.2), com.niclas-van-eyk.laravel-make-integration (2.3.5), de.espend.idea.php.annotation (8.0.0), net.king2500.plugins.PhpAdvancedAutoComplete (1.1.0), izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (6.18), ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2021.2)
```

Comment: Possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29406753/7644018

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the line limit length for different types of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873543/how-can-i-set-the-line-limit-length-for-different-types-of-files)

Comment: @PaulT.  @ JahnaviPaliwal Nope. The Run window should have nothing to do with the margins (visual guides / vertical lines) for the Editor. This has to be some different thing.

Comment: @FiroMOO What's your IDE version? There was an issue with the built-in Terminal that was limiting the line with to the default 80 symbols. Maybe it's the same thing here...

Comment: @PaulT  @ JahnaviPaliwal  unfortunately, this is not a solution. I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: @LazyOne  here,【PhpStorm 2021.1.3】, this is my IDE version what I`m using now. I tried to find the configuration carefully, however ,nothing useful.

Comment: @FiroMOO For me this has to be a limitation (custom logic) of that tool/script. Try this: run your own script (or if you can write your own text in that tool) that would output a long strings. For me it works fine (customs script) -- I can output 120 symbols long line with no issues. Therefore I think [it can be similar to this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239394#focus=Comments-27-4320675.0-0): the script detects that it's not a terminal (and cannot detect the actual width) and therefore assumes it's only 80 (?) symbols wide.

Comment: @FiroMOO Actually... `php artisan route:list` (that produces wide output) works just fine for me: https://i.imgur.com/qgAWdvl.png. The "hard wrap" limit that you are referring should have nothing to do with run/debug tool windows -- works fine for me as you can see...

Comment: BTW: try **disabling** the Material Theme UI plugin and restart the IDE -- any difference?

Comment: @LazyOne i deleted the Material Theme UI, run php artisan api:routes and  php artisan route:list ,it also only the 80 symbols wide .... Nothing has changed

Comment: @FiroMOO `Help | About`  and use Copy (Ctrl+C) there, then update your question with the info -- need to see what custom options you may have there. Maybe there is one that can help here...

Comment: @LazyOne OK，I listen to you.

Comment: @FiroMOO I've tried running with both `run.processes.with.pty=TRUE` and `FALSE` .. and saw no difference here (Windows 10). What I may suggest now: 1) Disable ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart IDE and try again (so no custom plugins are enabled at all) -- any difference? 2) If still the same: use `Help | Contact Support` to submit a ticket to PhpStorm Support Team, include there your `idea.log` (Help | Open Log in XXX) and describe your issue / link to the question on SO. No better ideas from me right now.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you bro. Thank you for the solution all about these. I am very happy to discuss with you and also grateful for your help. Your are right, maybe I should send a email to the Phpstorm support team to get the reason, if I have the solution, I'll tell you and update the post.